# Converting MySQL database dump into SQLite - INSERT syntax

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I'm trying to adapt my database dump into SQLite format, using the following command:
`cat db.sql | sqlite3 sqlite.db`

I get the following error:
`Error: near line 82: near ",": syntax error`
, where line 82 stands for:
`INSERT INTO files (file_id,file_name) VALUES` (the insert data in the following format `(31, 'file_name.pdf'),` come after that in the following lines).

According to [this tutorial](http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html) it is correct SQLite syntax for INSERT. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Line 82: `INSERT INTO files (file_id,file_name) VALUES`, line 83: `(31, 'file_name.pdf'),`.

Comment: can you still post lines before and after line 83? i need to see how your records are formatted.

Comment: In this table ('files'), all the values are formatted in the same way and the last line with values to insert is: `(55, 'filexxx.pdf');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having more than one record in one INSERT command is not standard SQL.

If you use this syntax, you'd need at least SQLite 3.7.11.